# Flat metric on compact surface minus a point

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $T^2$ be a compact smooth surface and let $p\in T^2$. Suppose that $T^2$ admits a symmetric $\left(0,2\right)$-tensor which is a flat Riemannian metric restricted to $T^2-\{p\}$. Is it true that $\chi(T)=0$?

Comment: $\|\operatorname{Rm}_g\|^2$ is a continuous function, so if it is zero in the complement of a point, it is zero everywhere. So if the restriction of $g$ to the complement of a point is flat, then $g$ is flat. The only compact surfaces which admit flat metrics are the torus and the Klein bottle, both of which have Euler characteristic zero.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: note that the $\left(0,2\right)$-tensor may fail to be positive definite at $p$

Comment: I see. I will leave my comment up as a warning.

Comment: Take the 2-sphere and remove the north pole.  This is stereographically diffeomorphic to the plane, which admits a flat metric.  Transport that flat metric back to the sphere.  It is flat away from the north pole.  But the sphere has nonzero Euler characteristic.

Comment: For every compact Riemann surface $S$ and a point $p\in S$ there is a harmonic function $u$ on $S\backslash p$.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: Note that the flat metric induced on the 2-sphere minus the north pole by the stereographic projection does not extend to a $\left(0,2\right)$-tensor on the whole sphere.

Comment: @GiannidelFiore Ah, sorry, I misread the question.  I too will leave the comment up as a warning :)

Comment: No. Take a flat metric with a single cone angle. These are smooth (in complex coordinates) because the cone angle is an integer multiple of 2 pi. You can get these metrics either from a holomorphic one form with a single zero, or branching over a torus with only one critical point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are explicit examples when $M$ is compact, connected, and $\chi(M)\le0$.

*Orientable case:*  Let $M$ be the 1-point compactification of the hyperelliptic Riemann surface defined in the affine plane $\mathbb{C}^2$ by
$$
y^2 = x^{2g+1}-1.
$$
This is a smooth Riemann surface of genus $g\ge1$ and hence $\chi(M) = 2-2g$.  The holomorphic $1$-form
$$
\omega = \frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2g+1}-1}}
$$
has only one zero (at the point $p$ where $x$ and $y$ have poles of order $2$ and $2g{+}1$ respectively).  Consequently, the smooth $(0,2)$-tensor
$$
h = \omega\circ\overline{\omega},
$$
which vanishes only at $p$ (and vanishes there to order $2g{-}1$), defines a flat metric on $M\setminus\{p\}$.

*Non-orientable case:*  Consider the Riemann surface $\tilde M$ that is the $2$-point compactification of the complex affine curve without real points
$$
x^{2g+2} + y^2 + 1 = 0,
$$
where $g\ge 1$. This is a hyperelliptic Riemann surface of genus $g$ and hence $\chi(\tilde M) = 2-2g$.  The holomorphic $1$-form 
$$
\omega = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y}
$$
has two zeroes, one at each of the two points where $x$ and $y$ have poles (of order $1$ and $g{+}1$, respectively), and hence $\omega$ has a zero of order $g{-}1$ at each of these points.

The antiholomorphic involution $C(x,y)=(\bar x,\bar y)$ has no fixed points and pulls $\omega$ back to $\overline{\omega}$.  Hence, the smooth quadratic form $\omega\circ\overline{\omega}$ is invariant under $C$ and thus descends to the quotient $M$ consisting of the pairs $\{q,C(q)\}$ for $q\in \tilde M$.  This $(0,2)$-form on $M$ vanishes at the point $\{p,C(p)\}\in M$ where $p\in \tilde M$ is (either) pole of $x$ and nowhere else.  Away from the point where it vanishes, it defines a flat metric on $M$.  Meanwhile, $M$ is a compact nonorientable surface of Euler characteristic $\chi(M) = 1-g\le 0$.

By the classification of surfaces, the above two cases cover all of the compact, connected surfaces $M$ with $\chi(M)\le 0$.

*Nonexistence when $\chi(M)>0$:*  In this case, there cannot be a smooth $(0,2)$-form $h$ on $M$ that vanishes only at one point and elsewhere defines a flat metric.  This will follow from the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.

First, a local fact: If $h$ is a smooth $(0,2)$-form on a (not necessarily compact) surface $M$ that degenerates at a single point $p$ but defines a (positive definite) metric with Gauss curvature $0$ everywhere else, then one can show that $p$ has an open neighborhood $B\subset M$ on which there exists a complex coordinate chart $\zeta:B\to\mathbb{C}$ that is smooth except possibly at $p$, satisfies $\zeta(p)=0$, and satisfies $h = L^2|\zeta|^{2(L-1)}|\mathrm{d}\zeta|^2$ on $B\setminus\{p\}$ for some constant $L>0$. (This uses the fact that $h$ near $p$ can be bounded above by an actual smooth metric.)

Now, suppost that $M$ is compact and let $D\subset B$ be the disk on which $|\zeta|<\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$. Apply the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem to the compact surface $C = M\setminus D$, which has the circle $|\zeta|=\epsilon$ as boundary and satisfies $\chi(C) = \chi(M)-1$.  Since the Gauss curvature of $h$ on $C$ is zero, Gauss-Bonnet yields
$$
-2\pi L = \int_{\partial C} \kappa_g\,\mathrm{ds} = 2\pi\chi(C) = 2\pi(\chi(M)-1),
$$
so $\chi(M) = 1-L < 1$.  Thus, $\chi(M)\le 0$ and $L$ is positive integer.  (This works even when the surface $C$ is non-orientable, using the 'unoriented' version of Gauss-Bonnet.  Alternatively, one could pass to the orientation double cover if necessary and argue there.  The result is the same.)

*Smoothing conical flat metrics:* It is known that, if $M$ is a compact, connected surface and $L_1,\ldots,L_m$ are positive real numbers such that $L_1+\cdots+L_m = m-\chi(M)$, then there exists a conformal structure on $M$ and $m$ points $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ and a flat Riemannian metric $h$ on $M\setminus\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$ such that each $p_i$ has a $p_i$-centered conformal coordinate chart $\zeta_i:B_i\to\mathbb{C}$ with the property that $h = (L_i)^2|\zeta_i|^{2(L_i-1)}|\mathrm{d}\zeta_i|^2$ on $B_i\setminus\{p_i\}$.  This $h$ will not extend smoothly in the $\zeta_i$ coordinate to $\zeta_i=0$ (i.e., $p_i$) unless $L$ is a (positive) integer.  However, defining a new (non-conformal) coordinate $z_i = |\zeta_i|^{(L_i-2)/2}\zeta_i$ on $B_i$, one finds that
$$
(L_i)^2|\zeta_i|^{2(L_i-1)}|\mathrm{d}\zeta_i|^2
= (L_i)^2 |z_i|^2|\mathrm{d}z_i|^2 + \bigl(1-(L_i)^2/4)\bigr)\bigl(\mathrm{d}(|z_i|^2)\bigr)^2.
$$
Thus, in the $z_i$ coordinate, $h$ is smooth at $z_i=0$ (i.e., $p_i$).  Using the $z_i$ to build a smooth (in fact, real-analytic) atlas on $M$ (keeping the conformal atlas at all the points of $M$ other than the $p_i$) yields a new smooth structure on $M$ in which $h$ extends real-analytically to all of $M$ and vanishes to order 2 at each of the $p_i$.

Comment: @MartindeBorbon and Robert Bryant, interesting construction, many thanks for your explanations. Robert Bryant, could you give more details on how the Gauss Bonnet Theorem can be used to rule out the case $\chi(M)>0$?

Comment: @GiannidelFiore:  Yes.  See above

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, that was a clever use of Gauss-Bonnet. What if $h$ simply degenerates but does not vanish at $p$?

Comment: @GiannidelFiore:  That doesn't matter.  As long as $h$ is positive definite and smooth except possibly at $p$, the normal form described above will hold on a punctured neighborhood of $p$, and that is all that is needed for the argument.  (Note that I did not claim that $\zeta$ must be smooth at $p$, and, in fact, I do not know that it would be.)

Comment: Of course, now I realize that the actual behavior of $h$ at $p$ is irrelevant to the construction of the complex coordinate chart $\zeta$. We can then use the same idea to conclude that $\chi(M)\leq0$ even when $h$ degenerates at two points. Do you know any counterexample in the case of three singular points?

Comment: @GiannidelFiore:  Well, yes.  You can have a smooth $h$ on the $2$-sphere that degenerates at three points, with each degenerate point having $L=1/3$ and the induced metric on the complement being flat.  More generally, I think you can do it with any three $L_i>0$ that add up to $1$.

Comment: Interesting! Can we build such an $h$ analytic?

Comment: @GiannidelFiore:  Yes, in the sense that there will be a real-analytic atlas on the 2-sphere such that the coefficients of $h$ in any chart of the atlas will be real-analytic.  In fact, when the $L_i$ are rational, you will be able to make them algebraic.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again for sharing your deep knowledge with this community. Season's Greetings

Comment: @GiannidelFiore:  You are welcome, and best wishes to you for the holidays as well.  If you want to know the details of the construction, let me know, and I'll try to find some time to put them into the answer during the holiday break.

Answer (score 0):

No. Each holomorphic quadratic differential on a compact Riemann surface induces a singular flat metric. The space of holomorphic quadratic differentials with a single zero is an orbifold of dimension $2g-2$, see https://math.indiana.edu/promotion/zgVpk567FZ-files/Bainbridge%20Chen%20Gendron%20Grushevsky%20Moller%20-%20Strata%20of%20k-Differentials.pdf